# Starting Bound and Started Services from another application

Tags: android, android-service

I need to start a service from `com.example.app1` and the service is part of a different application `com.example.app2`.

If the service in `com.example.app2` is implemented as a Started Service i.e. a Service which implements onStartCommand(), I get below error when I try to start the service:

```
Not allowed to start service Intent { cmp=com.example.app2/.SampleService }: app is in background uid null
```

I am using explicit intent to start the service:

```
Intent i = new Intent();

i.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.example.app2", "com.example.app2.SampleService"));

startService(i);
```

However if I implement `SampleService` as a Bound Service, I can bind to it even when `com.example.app2` is not running/foreground.

Are Bound services more secure than Started services? Why above difference in behavior?